# Can we better welcome this first-time poster?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What would be the main reason to avoid providing confidential data to the police by a company?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42349/what-would-be-the-main-reason-to-avoid-providing-confidential-data-to-the-police)

This Q starts with a note about being a first-time poster and not a native English speaker, etc.

So It's sad to see that it has 2 close votes already, and **no comments**.

Especially since this is from someone apparently writing a story (not just posting because it's fun in inself), can we as a community better welcome him by helping him to improve the question, and explain what may be deficient about it?